# Xcode WARNING: Unused Entity Issue: Unused Variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm working on this tutorial application and the code is giving me this warning:

> Xcode WARNING: Unused Entity Issue: Unused Variable

It's giving the error when executing this statement:

```
int newRowIndex = [self.checklist.items count];
```

What's causing it? Which steps should I take to resolve this?

Answer (score 7):

The variable `newRowIndex` is initialized but not being used anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

This warning just means that you created a variable, `newRowIndex`, but are not using it anywhere.

To silence the warning, use this `int` somewhere, like

```
int newRowIndex = [self.checklist.items count];
NSLog(@"New Row Index: %i", newRowIndex);
```

Comment: `newRowIndex` is not an object.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your build settings might have warnings flagged as errors.

You can silence warnings (not advised but if you just want to make sure you can build something) by searching for "Warning Policies" and turning "Treat Warnings as Errors" to "No".

Answer (score 1):

If you really want not to receive such warnings any more do the following:

1. Go to build settings of your project
2. Find "**Other Warning Flags**" option
3. Remove **-Werror** and **-Wno-unused-parameter**